# CMake to compile Matlab .m file to .exe using MCC

Tags: matlab, cmake, matlab-compiler

We're using the latest version of CMake(3.17), trying to compile a top level `.m` file into an executable on Matlab 2015b

I've done

`find_package(Matlab OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS MEX_COMPILER MCC_COMPILER)`

and it finds matlab.  I'm able to make MEX files using `matlab_add_mex()` (and access them from matlab), but the next step is to take the top level `.m` file and compile it to an executable so it can be sent off to a compute farm to run very large input vectors.

At the commandline, we just do `mcc -m simulation.m -I <required include paths> etc` and it works.   I want this to work in our CMake build environment with dependencies properly calculated (as best I can)

I assume I need to use `add_custom_command()` like what is mentioned here (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18183), and I assume I need to calculate the dependencies correctly.

Using this `cme.exe` line, I can get the dependencies out to a file:

```
matlab -wait -nosplash -nojvm -nodesktop -r "[fList,~] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('simulation.m');;for file = fList;fprintf(2,'%s\n',file{:});end;exit" -logfile output.txt
```

Is there a better way to do this?   This ends up launching matlab and blopping the output to a file, rather than stdout or whatever.  It's pretty dang slow to start up, as well.

I'm contemplating writing a python script or C program that embeds matlab that gets the information then prints it to stdout or just using `mcc` on the script that is supposed to calculate the dependencies, but that seems really, really convoluted for something that seems like a standard step in any repeatable build process.

So, any pointers?  I can't find a way to get the dependencies except inside a matlab command line, and I'd hope that CMake had m->exe (in addition to mex) in its wheelhouse.

fwiw, I took the following and put it into a file `get_dependencies.m`:

```
function print_dependencies(filename)
    [fList,~] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts(filename)
    for file = fList
        fprintf(1,'%s\n',file{:})
    end
end
```

and compiled it using

```
mcc -m get_dependencies.m
```

And when it runs, it whines about undefined variables:

```
Undefined variable "matlab" or class "matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts".
```